# Perform an action when application is started with 0 documents

Tags: swift, restore, launch, nsdocument

I have an NSDocument application that restores its windows when it is reopened. I would like to check the number of windows and perform an action (show a welcome window) if there are none.

I tried to check `NSDocumentController.shared().documents.count` but it seems I check it at the wrong time because it is always 0 in the delegate lifecycle functions.

How can I perform an action when the application is launched without restoring any windows?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do in my app: I just `dispatch_after` say, 0.5 seconds and *then* check the number of documents.  That allows me enough time to restore at least one document if there are any to restore. This does result in a noticeable delay, of course, but I feel that it's short enough that most users won't realize it (especially if your app is able to load up quickly enough).